# Lock screen option disappeared from Debian 9 and can't lock the OS

Tags: debian, screen-lock

I have tried the answers to this question, [Ubuntu 17.10 Screen lock not working and grey](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986182/ubuntu-17-10-screen-lock-not-working-and-grey) and tried installing `sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver`.

However, the problem is that I can't lock the computer anyway since there isn't any lock option in the menu nor does `gnome-screensaver-command -l` work properly.

It is the exact same problem discussed in this thread on Reddit, [Lock screen doesn't work](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/c41biz/lock_screen_doesnt_work/).

Answer (score 2):

Once my "Lock" menu item disappeared and at the same moment I couldn't lock the screen either. Then I checked the Gnome settings:

```bsh
gsettings list-recursively | grep lockdown
```

and I found that somehow option "disable-lock-screen" was set to true, which hides the menu item and prevents the screen from locking. Then I set it to false again:

```bsh
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'false'
```

and the "Lock" item is immediately returned and <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> starts working again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the display manager. I was using `sddm` and it was resolved after switching to `gdm3` package.

You can see the current display manager using this command:

```
cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

For switching display manager to `gdm3` you can simply run the following commands and select it as the default display manager:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm3
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

After all it is needed to rebooting the system.

Now you can lock the system either with the lock button or with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

**P.S** I have read somewhere that someone had the same issue with `lightdm` display manager package.